# why do inflate and root warn me?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() { 

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding 
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, AppCompatActivity(),true)
        setContentView(binding.root) 
    }
```

Comment: Warn you about what? Show messages you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to inflate your layout with `ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)` and make the `binding` variable private:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() { 

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding 
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) 
        setContentView(binding.root) 
    }
```

Comment: I didn`t get "Try to inflate your layout with ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)"

Comment: Change `ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, AppCompatActivity(),true)` to `ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)`

Comment: thanks. the answer was true. I reset my laptop and it works.